# How do i calculate four colors linear grdient?

Tags: linear-gradients

If I have four colours (A, B, C & D) on four points on a line and I want to fill with a gradient that blends nicely between the four colours how would I calculate the colour of the point E?
and A is starting point and D is ending point, before starting point and after ending point fill starting colour and end colour. inside line need to blend colour according to the distance and angle.

The closer E is to any of the other points, the strong that colour should affect the result.

[image]

I need like this one.
[image]

Any idea how to do that? Speed and simplicity is preferred to accuracy.

Comment: A color gradient is just a linear interpolation for each of the color channels. Use floating point — you need the resolution to sample for each pixel. Oh, and don’t make it more complex than you need. A-B is one gradient. B-C is another. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in simple terms, take point `ß` that is halfway between `A` and `B`. Assuming the use of RGB colors, if `A` is red `rgb(255, 0, 0)` and `B` is yellow `rgb(255, 255, 0)`, then `ß`'s color will be halfway between these: `rgb(255, 128, 0)`, that is, orange.

As you can see this can be calculated by using a weighted average per color channel - weighted by how close your point is to `A` and `B`.

Here's a code example you can run right here:

```js
const slider = document.getElementById("range")
const between = document.getElementById("between")

slider.addEventListener("input", ev => {
  const distFromA = ev.target.value
  const G = distFromA / 3.92
  // Not calculating R and B values, as these don't change in this specific example
  const R = 255
  const B = 0
  between.style.background = `rgb(${R}, ${G}, ${B})`
})
```

```css
#A { background: red; color: white; }
#B { background: yellow; }
#between { background: gainsboro; }
#between, #A, #B { display: inline-block; width: 50px; height: 50px; }
```

```html
<aside id=A>A</aside>
<aside id=between>ß</aside>
<aside id=B>B</aside>
<nav><input type=range min=0 max=1000 id=range /></nav>
```

Do this for each pixel and you get a gradient